# ¿Como puedo almacenar un dato editado dentro de un TextInput?

Tags: typescript, react-native, input

el cuestionamiento de mi problema es que tengo un dato que envio a un textinput y cuando lo edito y paso a otra pantalla de mi aplicación pasa el nuevo dato, pero si vuelvo a la pantalla de la edición se restablece el dato anterior.
estoy manejando React Native y typescript, para el envio de datos estoy usando route.params, y la navegación entre pantallas se distribuye entre drawer y stack navigation. si alguien sabe como puedo conservar ese dato editado lo agradeceria mucho.

A continuación muestro como esta mi TextInput:

```
<TextInput
          style={[
            stylesM.InputEditDatos,
            stylesL.JustifyAlign,
            stylesM.LeftInput,
          ]}
          keyboardType="numeric"
          onChangeText={(text) => setUser(text)}
          value={changeUser}
          editable={false}
        />
```

la variable **changeUser** tiene esta condición
**let changeUser = modification ? modification : usuario;**

la variable **usuario** es la primera que entra y **modification** es el usuario editado.